# Inverse laplace with fractional order

Tags: calculus, analysis, fractional-calculus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgXQ6.jpg)

$$
L^{-1}\left[ \frac{s^{\alpha}}{s^2\alpha+a^2}\right]\\
L^{-1}\left[ \frac{a}{s^2\alpha+a^2}\right]
$$

Can any one help me with those where alpha is fraction/rational number ... thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

From this [PDF](https://www.google.pl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjhg6jJiP3gAhVBwcQBHdzTABAQFjACegQIChAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdigitalcommons.wku.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D1115%26context%3Dtheses&usg=AOvVaw3QduvkwjMpdpkko5iTOh-y) on page 26:

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{s^{\alpha }}{s^{\beta }+a^2}\right](t)=t^{-1-\alpha +\beta }
   E_{\beta ,-\alpha +\beta }\left(-a^2 t^{\beta }\right)$$

$$\mathcal{L}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{a}{s^{\beta }+a^2}\right](t)=a t^{-1+\beta } E_{\beta ,\beta
   }\left(a^2 t^{\beta }\right)$$

where: $E_{\beta ,\beta -\alpha }\left(-a^2 t^{\beta }\right)$ and $E_{\beta ,\beta }\left(a^2 t^{\beta }\right)$ is [MittagLefflerE](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Mittag-LefflerFunction.html) function.